# Next JS SSR giving 404 error in aws amplify

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify, server-side-rendering

I'm using dynamic routing ssr in next js

```
      workflow-templates
      |
      |___ [[...page]]
```

is my folder structure it is working fine in local but giving 404 error page in amplify.
Am I missing any configuration in AWS?
I have added this in redirects editor, still not working

```
   {
      "source": "/workflow-templates/<*>",
      "target": "/workflow-templates/[[page]]/index.html",
      "status": "404-200",
      "condition": null
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I Shifted the website to vercel. Can't waste anymore time on half baked solution of amplify